# How to filter array angular

Tags: arrays, angular, filter

I have an array containing guidelines. Using a query I want to filter this array using only the guidelines that contains (part of) the query. I have the following code.

```
  filterguideline() {
    const query = this.recommendationForm.get('guideline').value;
        if (query !== "") {
            this.filteredguidelineList = this.Guidelines.filter(function (el) {
                return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            }.bind(this));
        } else {
            this.filteredguidelineList = [];
        }
    }
```

This does not really work. It does not filter the array, but simply shows all the values in the Guidelines array (irrespective of what the query contains).

Does anybody know the solution?

Comment: use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of plain javascript functions, so you don't have to call `.bind(this)`

Comment: upvote if the answer helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **`arrow`** function or like below,

```
    if (query !== "") {
        this.filteredguidelineList =  this.Guidelines.filter(t=>t.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    } else {
        this.filteredguidelineList = [];
    }
   return this.filteredguidelineList;
```

Using **`arrow`** function,

```
   this.filteredguidelineList = this.Guidelines.filter((el) => {
        return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
   });
```